# Why event missed in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, events

There're some events in the past, like the one in the image, but now I didn't find them in the firebase. Why?

[screenshot of event list in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijyos.png)

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance~

Comment: Welcome to SO. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question.  See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, links and images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks, the image here's an example, it's okay that it's not searchable or break.

Comment: It's not ok if it breaks as future readers won't have any idea what the question is about and that would make the question useless. Please clarify the question and include the code you're having difficulty with